# How to check if relation item is null

Tags: python, odoo

How can I check if a related object is null in openerp?

I have `my_object` which has a `supplier_invoice` field.

`my_object` is declared as:

```
_columns = {
        'supplier_invoice': fields.many2one('account.invoice',
                                            'commission invoice',
                                            ondelete='set null'),
}
```

and I want to do this:

```
if my_object.supplier_invoice:
     do_something()
```

but it doesn't work s it always returns a browse_record even if empty.

I am using openerp 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I had to test with :

```
if my_object.supplier_invoice.id:
    do_this()
```

the **id** is False when the record does not exist